# Update Path of JGrasp to use Different Compiler Settings

Tags: linux, java, path, ide, openjdk

I have a Cloud 9 programming hosted workspace from which I run a vnc client. This client is an X11 interface which I can access through an updating html page, and I have the following problem (yes, there is a reason for me to do it this way):

I have JGrasp installed, and it runs perfectly. However, I import a jar that has the minor version of 52, while JGrasp uses 51. I updated my java version with `sudo apt-get default-jdk`, which updated my jdk and jre version 7_71, which should be greater than 52 unless I can't math.

So, my question is this: how do I update the path of JGrasp, through its own interface, to have the new path supersede the old path.

Before you answer, "Add to the PATH in PATH/CLASSPATH", no, it is superseded by the old path.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

-- Before you answer, "Add to the PATH in PATH/CLASSPATH", no, it is superseded by the old path.

The paths in the PATH tab of PATH/CLASSPATH come before all others (path of Java used to run jGRASP itself, system PATH settings). Are you sure you added the path to the Java "bin" directory there? Also, you can turn on "Settings" > "Verbose Messages" to verify which javac and java are being used when you compile and run (it will be labeled "actual command sent" in the output.

Also, if you are using projects make sure you don't have a project-level PATH setting that will override one set at the workspace level.

The best thing though is to add the latest Java to your system PATH, so that jGRASP also will run under that version. Then turn off all PATH settings in jGRASP.

If this continues to be a problem, use "Help" > "Report a Bug" to let us know.

Comment: Hmm. It appears that a separate source I read is incorrect, as it stated that the PATH/CLASSPATH would be superseded by the system PATH. I'll give this a try.

Comment: You can see it in the default compiler environment for Java:

   PATH+=%<JAVA_BIN_DIR>%;

   PATH+=%<JGRASP_PATHS>%;

+= means prepend, so JAVA_BIN_DIR (the bin directory of the "Java" under which jGRASP is running) is added to the front, then JGRASP_PATHS, which includes the PATH/CLASSPATH settings (and for Java, nothing else) gets added in front of that.